# IP Address Changing

Tags: ip-address, ip

How can I go to the same website but use a different IP address every time?

Does TOR do this? I want to access a site but not have it know that the same IP is hitting it everytime.

TOR or http://anonymouse.org are these options or is there another tool for this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I'm sure TOR is good for it, but I'm not sure I would like you to interact with my website. Your intentions sound less than honourable.

Comment: If hit count is what you're after, you're better off grabbing a huge public proxy server list and making HTTP requests through those servers in randomized order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TOR, is an onion router.  So yes, your IP address as it appears to the website will be altered than if you were to directly connect to it.